# ldconfig configuration file cannot be opened i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I'm getting the warning message below when I install new libraries or run `ldconfig`.

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf: No such file or directory
```

I've been trying to install [CUDA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) 9.1 and [CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) on Ubuntu 18.04 for a couple of days with no luck, and I'm thinking that might be related or even the cause of the CUDA install failure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ldconfig errors caused by broken Nvidia symlink after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056740/ldconfig-errors-caused-by-broken-nvidia-symlink-after-upgrade-to-18-04)