# ldconfig errors caused by broken Nvidia symlink after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, 18.04, symbolic-link

I recently upgraded my computer from `17.10` to `18.04`. This involved an upgrade of the nvidia graphics driver from `nvidia-384` to `nvidia-driver-390`. However, I noticed that `nvidia-384` was still installed after the upgrade, and strangely seems to depend on `nvidia-driver-390`.

#### The problem:

Whenever I run `apt upgrade`, I get errors that look like

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
```

When I look for `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf`, I can see that it is a broken symlink to `/etc/alternatives/i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf`, which itself is a broken symlink to `/usr/lib/nvidia-384-prime/alt_ld.so.conf`. The entire directory `/usr/lib/nvidia-384-prime` does not even exist.

#### What I have already tried:

I tried purging all nvidia packages using:

```
sudo apt purge --autoremove nvidia*
```

I then rebooted (and checked that nouveau drivers were loaded), reinstalled `nvidia-driver-390`, and rebooted again.

Now I no longer have the `nvidia-384` package (only `nvidia-driver-390` which seems to be working normally), but the broken symlinks and error messages are still there. Moreover, there is a directory `/usr/lib/nvidia-384`, but I assume that should be gone since I do not have `nvidia-384`.

#### My question:

Can/should I just remove the broken symlinks to stop these error messages? Or is there some other (cleaner) way which would remove these, as well as any other extraneous files/directories/links that may be on my computer (like the `/usr/lib/nvidia-384` directory)?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I just tried renaming `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf` to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf.bak` to "remove" it (in the eyes of `ldconfig`)...it seems to "resolve" the issue in that I no longer get `ldconfig` errors. But I still have the extraneous `nvidia-384` directory which I do not know what to do with...again not sure if there is a clean way to remove all of the unnecessary files related to this.

Comment: Check this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/900285/libegl-so-1-is-not-a-symbolic-link It may be a duplicate but I am not sure. Anyway, the script in the last answer helped me with what I think is the same problem.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I do not think that is the same as my issue unfortunately :(

I do not have a `/usr/lib/nvidia-390` directory (though again, `nvidia-driver-390` is installed and working), and the only contents of my `/usr/lib/nvidia-384` directory are two more broken symlinks, neither of which match the file referenced by the answers to that post.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't it.  The problem went away when I upgraded to 18.04.

Comment: Did you actually run `sudo ldconfig` from a terminal?  It might be able to fix any ld errors you might be getting.

Comment: @Terrance running `sudo ldconfig` gives the same error

Comment: You might have to remove them both and clean install `nvidia-driver-396` or `nvidia-driver-390`.  Probably not good to have old mixed with new drivers.

Comment: @Terrance What does "them both" mean? As my post says, I tried removing all nvidia packages already, and clean installed `nvidia-driver-390`...

Comment: If you can't remove 384 as well, you might be out of luck and need to clean install.  That is one thing I bumped into when I tried to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 soon after it was released.  I ended up clean installing 18.04 to get rid of the upgrade errors I was getting.

Comment: I did remove `nvidia-384`. There just appears to be some residual files/links from it that maybe aren't being removed by `apt purge`? I'm not sure if that is actually the issue though...`nvidia-driver-390` works well (both before and after clean install), so I don't think a clean Ubuntu install should be necessary (I can just live with the warning from ldconfig...)

Comment: please check whether the link is valid or not. "ls -l /etc/ld.so.conf.d/Cx86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf" if so, "sudo cp /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_egl_conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d/Cx86_64-linux-gnu_EGL.conf"

Answer (score 2):

Had more or less the same problem after an update (ldconfig error). The following command deleted all invalid links:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf
```

Comment: That got rid of those links in `/etc/alternatives/`, which is nice. Thank you! Any idea about other leftover files from the `nvidia-384` package that were not removed/cleaned up correctly?

Comment: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for i386-linux-gnu_egl_conf`